# incorrect value of name attribute in event object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I read about using a single handler for multiple input fields. When I'm trying to use that approach -> using `event.target.value`, I am getting just the first letter of what I entered in the input. Can anyone please help me on what I am doing wrong.

```
class AddContactForm extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.name = "";
        this.email = ""
        this.phone = "";
    }


    componentDidUpdate() {
        console.log("updated");
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        console.log("unmounted");
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        console.log("mounted");
    }

    handleOnChange(event) {
        [event.target.name] = event.target.value;
        console.log(event)
        console.log(event.target.name);
        console.log(event.target.value);
    }

    addContact() {
        console.log("add");
        this.props.addContactHandler({
            name: this.name,
            email: this.email,
            phone: this.phone
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <div className="mx-auto">
                    <div class="mb-3 row">
                        <label for="username" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Name</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name='name' id="username" onChange={this.handleOnChange.bind(this)} />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="mb-3 row">
                        <label for="mobileNumber" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Mobile Number</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="phone" id="mobileNumber" onChange={this.handleOnChange.bind(this)} />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="mb-3 row">
                        <label for="emailId" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Email</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="emailId" name="email" onChange={this.handleOnChange.bind(this)} />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <button className="btn btn-primary w-25" onClick={this.addContact.bind(this)}>Add</button>
                </div>
            </React.Fragment>
        )
    }
}

export default AddContactForm;
```

inside handle on change, the value of [event.target.name] always shows whatever was my first input alphabet. for If I am writong abcd ing input, ikt'll keep showing me a .

Where am I going wrong ?

Comment: You should only bind your methods to the `this` object in the class's `constructor`. [ReactJS Style Guide](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript/tree/master/react#methods)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with the first line of code in this function.

```
handleOnChange(event) {
        [event.target.name] = event.target.value;
        console.log(event)
        console.log(event.target.name);
        console.log(event.target.value);
    }
```

That changes the `HTML Input element name`'s first letter to the `first letter of the input value` you have typed.

Add with the following log

```
  handleOnChange = (event) => {
    [event.target.name] = event.target.value;
    console.log(event);
    console.log(event.target);
    console.log(event.target.name);
    console.log(event.target.value);
  };
```

[image]

**Solution**

To change the class variable dynamically,
instead of

```
[event.target.name] = event.target.value;
```

use

```
this[event.target.name] = event.target.value;
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't set the state properly in both `constructor` and `handleChange` functions.

Try this

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class AddContactForm extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      name: "",
      email: "",
      phone: ""
    };
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    console.log("updated");
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    console.log("unmounted");
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    console.log("mounted");
  }

  handleOnChange(event) {
    this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
  }

  addContact() {
    console.log("add");
    console.log(this.state);
    // this.props.addContactHandler(this.state);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <div className="mx-auto">
          <div class="mb-3 row">
            <label for="username" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">
              Name
            </label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input
                type="text"
                class="form-control"
                name="name"
                id="username"
                onChange={this.handleOnChange.bind(this)}
              />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="mb-3 row">
            <label for="mobileNumber" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">
              Mobile Number
            </label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input
                type="text"
                class="form-control"
                name="phone"
                id="mobileNumber"
                onChange={this.handleOnChange.bind(this)}
              />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="mb-3 row">
            <label for="emailId" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">
              Email
            </label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input
                type="email"
                class="form-control"
                id="emailId"
                name="email"
                onChange={this.handleOnChange.bind(this)}
              />
            </div>
          </div>
          <button
            className="btn btn-primary w-25"
            onClick={this.addContact.bind(this)}
          >
            Add
          </button>
        </div>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default AddContactForm;
```

Check console logs
[image]

Code sandbox URL => https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-feather-jcj99?file=/src/App.js:0-2241

Comment: @Amit Gupta, Check this out !!

Comment: but what If I try to do this without state. I mean just with class attributes ?

Also, in logs i can see that value of name attribute is coming as just the first letter of entered input what is the reason for this strange behaviour ?

Comment: @AmitGupta, I figured it out. That's due to `[event.target.name] = event.target.value;` line of code in your code. It changes the name of the input element to first letter of the value you have typed.

Comment: yup I realised it too ! but now the question is that instead of this.email how can I give an expression where I can dynamically assign a value to  a class variable. Like this.[event.target.value]. I know this syntax is incorrect but is there a way to do that ?

Comment: @Amit Gupta, Try this `this[event.target.name] = event.target.value;`

Comment: @ Amila Senadheera Thanks a lot !
Working fine now :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want use a generic input change handler for all inputs you can get the `name` and `value` from `event.target`. Then create an object from each of them like `{name]: value}` to pass to `this.setState`.

```
  handleOnChange = (event) => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    this.setState({
      [name]: value
    });
  }
```

```
class AddContactForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      name: "",
      email: "",
      phone: ""
    };
  }

  handleOnChange = (event) => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    this.setState({
      [name]: value
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <label>
          Name
          <input
            type="text"
            name="name"
            onChange={this.handleOnChange}
            value={this.state.name}
          />
        </label>

        <label>
          Mobile Number
          <input
            type="text"
            name="phone"
            onChange={this.handleOnChange}
            value={this.state.phone}
          />
        </label>

        <label>
          Email
          <input
            type="email"
            name="email"
            onChange={this.handleOnChange}
            value={this.state.email}
          />
        </label>

        <pre>{JSON.stringify(this.state, null, 2)}</pre>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default AddContactForm;
```

[image: Edit epic-rubin-sgqex]

---

If all of your fields are identical, you can even dynamically render them by mapping over the keys of the state object:

```
class AddContactForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      name: "",
      email: "",
      phone: ""
    };
  }

  handleOnChange = (event) => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    this.setState({
      [name]: value
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        {Object.keys(this.state).map((key) => (
          <label>
            {key}
            <input
              type="text"
              name={key}
              onChange={this.handleOnChange}
              value={this.state[key]}
            />
          </label>
        ))}

        <pre>{JSON.stringify(this.state, null, 2)}</pre>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default AddContactForm;
```

[image: Edit spring-hill-ek0s8]

Answer (score 0):

you should render this component for this work can use the state and set state ...

```js
class AddContactForm extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            name: "",
            email: "",
            phone: ""
        }

    }


    componentDidUpdate() {
        console.log("updated");
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        console.log("unmounted");
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        console.log("mounted");
    }

    handleOnChange(event) {
        this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value })
        console.log(event)
        console.log(event.target.name);
        console.log(event.target.value);
    }

    addContact() {
        console.log("add");
         this.props.addContactHandler(this.state);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <div className="mx-auto">
                    <div class="mb-3 row">
                        <label for="username" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Name</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name='name' id="username" onChange={this.handleOnChange.bind(this)} />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="mb-3 row">
                        <label for="mobileNumber" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Mobile Number</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="phone" id="mobileNumber" onChange={this.handleOnChange.bind(this)} />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="mb-3 row">
                        <label for="emailId" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Email</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="emailId" name="email" onChange={this.handleOnChange.bind(this)} />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <button className="btn btn-primary w-25" onClick={this.addContact.bind(this)}>Add</button>
                </div>
            </React.Fragment>
        )
    }
}

export default AddContactForm;
```